# How to properly subclass SKNode when there is no init method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sknode

SKNode only offers `+node` method.

If you do this:

```
+ (instancetype)node {
    CustomNode *body = [CustomNode node]; // infinite loop
}
```

If you do this:

```
+ (instancetype)node {
    CustomNode *body = [super node]; // instance of SKNode, not CustomNode
}
```

How do you subclass a class that only has a convenience constructor in such way that you can override the constructor? Or is it best practice to create your own `+customNode` method?

Answer (score 7):

No one's saying you can't use `[... alloc] init]` on an SKNode subclass. After all, SKNode is a subclass of NSObject. `+node` is just a convenience method.

```
+ (instancetype)node {
    CustomNode *body = [[self alloc] init];
    return body;
}
```

There's nothing wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (instancetype)node {
    CustomNode *body = [CustomNode node]; // infinite loop
}
```

And infinite loop is the expected result, since you are calling the same method. As for the other one:

```
+ (instancetype)node {
    CustomNode *body = [super node]; // instance of SKNode, not CustomNode
}
```

The goal here is for you to make your `CustomNode` get initialised as expected. It's the same thing when you create a `UIViewController` for example:

```
if ( self == [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle])
```

You want to do the standard initialisation. What you do after, is what makes your `CustomNode` a custom node. :)

```
+ (instancetype)node {
    CustomNode *body = [super node];
    // My own logic goes here

   return body;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually to do nothing. The default implementation of `+[SKNode node]` returns an instance of whatever class *or subclass* it is called on.

Don't override `+[SKNode node]` in your subclass. Instantiate instances of your class as in the following example:

```
// In MyScene.m
// MyNode is a SKNode subclass

- (void)createNewNode
{
    MyNode *node = [MyNode node]; // node is of type MyNode

    [self addChild:node];
}
```